# Post per page not working if no category specified

Tags: query-posts, loop

I'm going crazy...

```
<?php query_posts(array('cat' => 3, 'posts_per_page' => 1)); ?>
```

This shows 1 post (there is two in the category) >> OK

```
<?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 1)); ?>
```

This shows 4 posts (there is four in the whole database) >> WTF? :P

This is crazy... or am I ?

Note: I only have one loop (this one), in this template.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change your array to exclude sticky, then this should work

`get_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an array with only one paramater.  Change your code to: 
`<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1'); ?>`

Comment: Thx Rachel. Well, it doesn't work either :) But I know why. This thing has been driving me nuts for hours now. Guess what, all my posts are set as "sticky"... but I don't know how to work around that... Any idea?

Comment: This query should work with sticky or non-stick posts:
`query_posts('showposts=1');`

Comment: Actually no, it shouldn't (but yes, this is weird/silly). You have to use caller_get_posts=1  to exclude sticky posts from being returned at the top of your query results...

Comment: You may want answer the question for me please, as I'm a noob (not enough reputation yet), I can't. Thx :)

Comment: Clarification question: did showposts=1 not display any posts at all?

Comment: It displays all four posts... I answered my question already. Thank you anyway.